# How to resize one static rectangular banner to several sizes in PS or Sketch?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, sketch-app, resize, automation, photoshop-scripting

Let's say I need to make a set of banners in 25 sizes. 
Is it possible to make only one design of rectangular banner and resize it to 24 other sizes afterwards using scripts?

The only way I see now is to pre-produce a template with fixed layout and slots for smart objects. But I want to make the process more flexible. Is there any PS or Sketch script that will resize one banner without messing up the elements inside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no one click fix. I doubt such a script could even exist, if you resize a button from a ie 600x300 banner to a 120x600, the font size in the button would be unreadable. And then you have the placement etc...

Sketch is not the right software to use for this, especially since the resizing of text in symbols is currently still an issue.

I have to create similar bannersets, often with 10-30 different sizes. It's boring and time consuming.

I personally use a template file I created that has smart objects for things like the logo, the CTA, the background image etc. I can replace these in 1 click, and I try to make my design so that I can kind of work with the template instead of against it. Use smart objects for as many things as possible so that making changes is fast.